# Tuples without (declare-datatypes)?

Tags: z3, smt

I wrote a large-ish library in the Z3 dialect of SMT-LIB.  Unfortunately, my use of `(declare-datatypes)` to create tuples means that I cannot set the logic to `QF_AUFBV` as I desire.  This has the side effect of making my scripts slower (sometimes timing out) than when I manually create the formulas programmatically and solve using `QF_ABV`.  Thus, I want to eliminate `(declare-datatypes)` from my script.  Most of the data types can be encoded as bit vectors.  However, the most important sort in the library is a tuple of a bitvector term and three arrays.  Is there a solution where I can make a sort like this, while still using `QF_AUFBV` logic?

Answer (score 0):

You can always concatenate the bitvectors of the tuple and extract the relevant half whenever needed.

Comment: Yes, I can replace the enumerated and variant types with bitvectors.  But it doesn't seem possible to create a type that mixes both bitvectors and arrays without using `(declare-datatypes)`.